# Check if ASP.NET MVC 3 installed and if it is not install it from internet with Inno Setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, installation, inno-setup

I want to check the registry for the existence of Asp.net mvc 3. If it is not contained in the system, MVC 3 itself must itself be installed from internet automatically. I have a code below for it, but I have a compiler error for the line "AddProduct(bla bla bla)". It says "Unknown Identifier 'AddProduct'". Why is that anyway?

```
 const
AspNetMVC3_url = 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/1/F31EF055-3C46-4E35-   AB7B-3261A303A3B6/AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe';
 procedure AspNetMVC3();
 var
version: cardinal;
 begin
if not RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\  {37C939A9-427D-4F06-A14C-5C672EF51C6C}') then
 AddProduct('AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe','',CustomMessage('AspNetMVC3_title'),CustomMessage   ('AspNetMVC3_size'),AspNetMVC3_url,false,false);
end;
```

Comment: What is that `AddProduct` supposed to be ?

Comment: it is supposed to download mvc3

Comment: Well, it is not a Inno Setup function. It is then either part of some 3rd party downloader or something ASP specific. Which option is it ? Or from where did you get that line of code ? In Inno Setup, the [`InnoTools Downloader`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50) is usually used.